# How to install Pylama with Poetry?

Tags: python, pip, lint, python-poetry, pylama

I want to install Pylama because it has other Linting packages. I'm using Poetry for Package Managment, but I don't know how to do this.

Pylama's documents indicate that if you use pip you have to use `pip install pylama[all]`, but I can't find how to do it with Poetry. I have this in my `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
 python = "^3.8"
 Pillow = "^9.0.0"
 matplotlib = "^3.5.1"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
 pylama[all] = "^8.3.7"
```

With that I only install the basic from pylama, the same as doing `pip install pylama`.

Afterwards, I created a virtual environment with virtualenv and use `pip install pylama[all]`, and I it showed this error: `ERROR: pylint 2.12.2 has requirement mccabe<0.7,>=0.6, but you'll have mccabe 0.7.0 which is incompatible.`If I do pip freeze after the installation, I can see `pylint==2.12.2`. I don't know if it is because of this error that Poetry don't install all, but in that case I guess it should install mypy, eradicate, radon, and vulture, but nope.

I'm running this in Lubuntu, with Python 3.8.10

Hope someone can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[]` indicates that you want to install extras provided by the package. With poetry you can do this via cli like this:

```
poetry add pylama[all]
```

(Dependending on your shell it might be necessary to put quotes around `pylama[all]`)

In the `pyproject.toml` it will than look like this:

```
pylama = {extras = ["all"], version = "^8.3.7"}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I was using poetry init, that way I could't add those packages